# Coq QArith division by zero is zero, why?

Tags: coq, divide-by-zero, rational-numbers

I noticed that in Coq's definition of rationals the inverse of zero is defined to zero.  (Usually, division by zero is not well-defined/legal/allowed.)

```
Require Import QArith.
Lemma inv_zero_is_zero: (/ 0) == 0. 
Proof. unfold Qeq. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Why is it so?

Could it cause problems in calculations with rationals, or is it safe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, it is absolutely safe.

When we say that division by zero is not well-defined, what we actually mean is that zero doesn't have a multiplicative inverse. In particular, we can't have a function that computes a multiplicative inverse for zero. However, it *is* possible to write a function that computes the multiplicative inverse for all other elements, and returns some arbitrary value when such an inverse doesn't exists (e.g. for zero). This is exactly what this function is doing.

Having this inverse operator be defined everywhere means that we'll be able to define other functions that compute with it without having to argue explicitly that its argument is different from zero, making it more convenient to use. Indeed, imagine what a pain it would be if we made this function return an `option` instead, failing when we pass it zero: we would have to make our entire code monadic, making it harder to understand and reason about. We would have a similar problem if writing a function that requires a proof that its argument is non-zero.

So, what's the catch? Well, when trying to *prove* anything about a function that uses the inverse operator, we will have to add explicit hypotheses saying that we're passing it an argument that is different from zero, or argue that its argument can *never* be zero. The lemmas about this function then get additional preconditions, e.g.

```
forall q, q <> 0 -> q * (/ q) = 1
```

Many other libraries are structured like that, cf. for instance the definition of the [field axioms](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/Ssreflect.ssralg.html) in the algebra library of MathComp.

There *are* some cases where we want to internalize the additional preconditions required by certain functions as type-level constraints. This is what we do for instance when we use *length-indexed vectors* and a safe `get` function that can only be called on numbers that are in bounds. So how do we decide which one to go for when designing a library, i.e. whether to use a rich type with a lot of extra information and prevent bogus calls to certain functions (as in the length-indexed case) or to leave this information out and require it as explicit lemmas (as in the multiplicative inverse case)? Well, there's no definite answer here, and one really needs to analyze each case individually and decide which alternative will be better for that particular case.