# Recovering implicit information from existentials in Coq

Tags: coq, real-number

Suppose we have something like this:

Suppose x is a real number. Show that if there is a real number y such that (y + 1) / (y - 2) = x, then x <> 1".

If one formulates it in an obvious way: `forall x : R, (exists y, ((y + 1) * / (y - 2)) = x) -> x <> 1`, one runs into an issue very soon.

We have an assumption of existence of `y` such that `((y + 1) * / (y - 2)) = x)`. Am I wrong to assume that this should also imply that `y <> 2`? Is there a way to recover this information in Coq?

Surely, if such `y` exists, then it is not 2. How does one recover this information in Coq - do I need to explicitly assume it (that is, there is no way to recover it by existential instantiation somehow?).

Of course, `destruct H as [y]` just gives us `((y + 1) * / (y - 2)) = x)` for `y : R`, but now we don't know `y <> 2`.

Answer (score 4):

> Am I wrong to assume that this should also imply that `y <> 2`?

Yes. In Coq, division is a total, unconstrained function: you can apply it to any pair of numbers, including a zero divisor.  If you want to assume `y <> 2`, you need to add that as an explicit assumption to your lemma.

You may find this scary: how could we be allowed to divide something by zero? The answer is that it doesn't matter, as long as you do not try to argue that `0 * (x / 0) = x`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282819/coq-qarith-division-by-zero-is-zero-why) discusses the issue in  more detail.

Answer (score 3):

The real numbers in Coq are defined axiomatically, i.e. they are just names associated with types, there are no definitions attached to the names. There are basic numbers (`R0`, `R1`) and operations on reals (`Rplus`, `Rmult`, etc.) which do not get executed, i.e. operations are not functions. In a sense one just builds real numbers by constructing them out of those operations just like with data constructors (but we cannot pattern-match on reals).

The above means that, e.g. `1/0` is a valid real number. It's just the premises of the axioms for real numbers prohibit some simplifications involving expressions like that: we cannot rewrite expressions like `1/0 * 0` to `1` (though, we *can* rewrite it to `0`).

Here is how we can show that we cannot derive `y <> 2` from an expression like

```
(y + 1) / (y - 2) = x
```

because we are allowed to use "strange" real numbers:

```
From Coq Require Import Reals.
Open Scope R.

Goal ~ (forall x y : R, (y + 1) / (y - 2) = x -> y <> 2).
  unfold "_ - _"; intros contra; specialize (contra ((2+1)/0) 2).
  rewrite Rplus_opp_r in contra.
  intuition.
Qed.
```